# A contract that generates another contract

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, action

If I want to create a smart contract with an action 'Create Game' and on calling that action a new contract be formed, how is it possible?

Comment: I don't think `setcode` is in the available contract API so I don't think it's possible directly

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a 'new' contract, but you can call another contract's function and create a new object in that contract to save the state.

You can refer to eosio.token inline functions get_balance/get_supply where both functions are accessible from any other contracts by just initializing eosio.token in your own contract.

edit: It is not possible to create an object in another contract as it will consume ram

Answer (score 0):

Think of your contract as a factory. You keep a collection of games. Each game is an instance of a struct called game - it has all the state fields of a game. When someone creates a new game you just add one to the collection.